# Build error on Substrate Toolbox - rust nightly not installed

Tags: substrate-node, srtool

I'm customising the `srtool (Substrate runtime toolbox)` for our chain built based on `substrate`.

The srtool docker image was built successful, but when Github running test against myChain, it failed with an error

```
  Rust nightly not installed, please install it!
  parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 2
  Error: Process completed with exit code 4.
```

Here's how rustup was updated, and toolchain are installed and target is setup in In `Dockerfile`

```sh
RUN echo $SHELL && \
    curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- --default-toolchain $RUSTC_VERSION -y  && \
    . $CARGO_HOME/env && \
    rustup myChain add stable ${RUSTC_VERSION} && \
    rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain $RUSTC_VERSION && \
    chmod -R a+w $RUSTUP_HOME $CARGO_HOME && \
    rustup show && rustc -V
```

Not sure why the docker image was built successfully with nightly, but failed in the test.

```
      - name: Run srtool build for ${{ matrix.chain }}
        id: srtool_build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these commands one by one and check is it work?
let me know its works or not.

```
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly-2023-01-01-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
 rustup install nightly-2023-01-01
 rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly
 rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly-2023-01-01-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
 rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly-2023-01-01-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```